# Can nested LookUp be done?

Tags: sharepoint, nested, max, lookup, powerapps

Hi again dear stackoverflowers!

I have one column in Sharepoint for an ID number (say that the number is 29) and another column that for that ID holds different subIDs (29.1, 29.2, 29.3, etc.).

What I need is that my PowerApp looks up into the Sharepoint list and takes the maximum subID number associated with the ID given, and automatically sums 0.1, because I do not want people to introduce two equal subIDs.

I'll give you the formula I tried (but the problem is that **StartsWith is for text and Max is for numbers)**, so if you have any ideas about how can it be solved or you have **any function that works with both text and numbers** I would really appreciate it:

`LookUp(my_list.'Prueba', StartsWith('Prueba' , DataCardValue9_2.Text), Max('Prueba')+0.1)`

Another thing I tried was to **nest LookUp functions**, but that did not work either, do you know if **that can be done?**

`LookUp(my_list, Prueba = DataCardValue9_2.Text + 0.3 , Max(Prueba) + 0.1) & LookUp(my_list, Prueba = DataCardValue9_2.Text + 0.2 , Max(Prueba) + 0.1) & LookUp(my_list, Prueba = DataCardValue9_2.Text + 0.1 , Max(Prueba) + 0.1)`

**Thank you very much** for your time and help.

Comment: What is type of ID and subIDs? columns of numbers? or column of strings? And what are the column names for ID and subIDs. And finally are you sing DataCardValue9_2.Text to look up the associated ID?

Answer (score 0):

You must convert your column to a number datatype. Value() function for number.

Please do check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-value